# How to create a function which depending in a conditions delays a nested loop or not

Tags: r, function, loops, nested, conditional-statements

I need to create a **function** which depends on 2 variables and a table(?) (x,y,table). First this function need to loop through every row in a table and dependending of 'X' column value (1 or 0) take a different action:

When x column = 1 then copy the row 'y' times. Then in a nested loop create a column numerating from 1 to y the times the row was copied.

When x column = 0 then just leave the row how it is.

An example of the input would be

[image]

the output would be

[image]

I tried doing the next code but honestly im not very good with loops.

```
    My_function <- function(x,y,table) {

      for (i in 1:nrow(table)) {

        if(table[,which(colnames(table) = as.character(x)] == 1){
          dummy = table[i,]
          final_dummy = NULL

          for(j in 1:dummy$y){
            dummy_2 = dummy
            final_dummy = rbind(final_dummy,dummy_2)
                                                     }
        } else if(table[,which(colnames(table) = as.character(x)] == 0){
              table[i,] 
      }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and R. Thank you for putting up images of your input and output  expectations. It would help answerers if you include your input data in a dataframe format e.g. df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 2, 3), b = c("a", "b", "c")) obviously with your own data!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col = c(letters[1:3]), x = c(1, 0, 1), y = c(2, 3, 4))

df %>% 
  mutate(uncY = if_else(x == 0, 1, y)) %>% 
  uncount(uncY, .id = "id")

# A tibble: 7 x 4
  col       x     y    id
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1 a         1     2     1
2 a         1     2     2
3 b         0     3     1
4 c         1     4     1
5 c         1     4     2
6 c         1     4     3
7 c         1     4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write the function as :

```
My_function <- function(data) {
  out <- data[with(data, rep(seq_along(col), pmax(colx * coly, 1))), ]
  rownames(out) <- NULL
  out$num <- with(out, ave(colx, col, FUN = seq_along))
  return(out)
}
```

and call it

```
My_function(df)

#  col colx coly num
#1   a    1    2   1
#2   a    1    2   2
#3   b    0    3   1
#4   c    1    4   1
#5   c    1    4   2
#6   c    1    4   3
#7   c    1    4   4
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(col = letters[1:3], colx = c(1, 0, 1), coly = c(2, 3, 4))
```